# Scala: unpacking an Object: how do I know the type

Tags: class, scala, implicit

Apache Avro GenericRecord.get(colName) did the (dirty?) trick of returning an Object so it can return whatever type it wants. The Object contains other types: String, Int, Date, etc. The values can be null.

Example:

```
val one = genericRecord.get("hello")     // "hello" resolves to an Int
val two = genericRecord.get("goodbye")   // "goodbye" resolves to a String
```

"one" and "two" are of type Object, but they are "actually" an Int and String, respectively.

I'm trying to write an implicit class method to return an Option(`<actual_type`>) with the result (to avoid dealing with the null case), so I can write

```
val myVal = genericRecord.getWithType("hello")
```

and have myVal be of type Option[Int].

Tried the following:

```
one match { 
    case i: Int => Option(i.asInstanceOf[Int])
    case s: String => Option(s.toString)
}
```

But I get

```
error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
  found   : Int
  required: Object
       case x: Int =>
               ^
```

Matching on

```
one.getClass
```

doesn't work either. 
Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use GenericData.Record.getSchema to find out the "real" DB types.

Comment: You may need to match on `java.lang.Integer` (which extends `Object`) instead of `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

When coming back from Java interoperability,  Scala interprets `Object` as `AnyRef`. Since `Int` is not a subtype of `AnyRef`, the pattern matcher does not let you do a "stupid" thing.

You can force the interpretation as `Any` simply by ascribing the result of `get` with `: Any`:

```
val one = genericRecord.get("hello"): Any
```